Thread-Safe Data Transfer Architecture in Real-Time Systems (C Language)
Short:
I have a model that takes care of communication with a device. The model has two threads: one for communication (read and write) and one for logging the results. Ensuring thread safety using mutexes is not a problem.
Now, I have the main program that uses this model to get/send values to/from the device. Let's say I have a buffer. The main program itself is multithreaded, meaning I need to protect the buffer between multiple threads and while communicating with the device model.
Using one global mutex for everything goes against the model principle and would make everything more complicated.
How can I build a thread-safe interface between the communication model and the main program?
Long:
Allow me to illustrate the problem with a straightforward example.
I have a device model structured as follows:

device.h

#ifndef DEVICE_H
#define DEVICE_H

struct d_in {
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
};

struct d_out {
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
};

struct device {
    struct d_in input;
    struct d_out output;
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
    sem_t sem_data;
};

void *communication_thread(void *arg);
void *logging_thread(void *arg);

void _init_device();
void _read_input(struct d_in *input);
void _write_output(const struct d_out *output);

//////////////////////////////////////
void transfer_data(struct *dev)    // that what I want as interface

#endif /* DEVICE_H */



device.c

#include "device.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "special_card_for_reading_from_device_.h"

static struct device dev;

void init_device() {
    dev.input.x = 0;
    dev.input.y = 0;
    dev.input.z = 0;
    dev.output.x = 0;
    dev.output.y = 0;
    dev.output.z = 0;
    pthread_mutex_init(&dev.mutex, NULL);
    sem_init(&sem_data,NULL, NULL);
}

void read_input() {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&dev.mutex);
    read_fucntion(&dev.input);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&dev.mutex);
}

void write_output() {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&dev.mutex);
    write_fucntion(&dev.output);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&dev.mutex);
}

void *communication_thread(void *arg) {
    while (1) {
        read_input();
        write_output();
        sem_post(&sem_data);
        sleep(1); // Simulating communication delay
    }
    return NULL;
}

void *logging_thread(void *arg) {
    FILE *fp = fopen("log.txt", "w");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        perror("Error opening log file");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while (1) {
        sem_wait(&sem_data);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&dev.mutex);
        fprintf(fp, "Input: %d %d %d\n", dev.input.x, dev.input.y, dev.input.z);
        fprintf(fp, "Output: %d %d %d\n\n", dev.output.x, dev.output.y, dev.output.z);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&dev.mutex);
        sleep(2); // Logging interval
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return NULL;
}


then I have the main program with a thread transfer
void *transfer(void *arg) {
    while (1) {
        // how to protect this section
        transfer(&buffer_dev_data);
        //////////////////////////
        sleep(1);
    }
    return NULL;
}
void *another_thread(void *arg) {
    while (1) {
        // how to protect this section
        operations_on_bufffer(buffer_dev_data);
        //////////////////////////
        sleep(1);
    }
    return NULL;
}

Could using two mutexes to protect the same line cause issues like deadlock? If I use a mutex inside the transfer function and another one outside it, it will ultimately look the same as follows:
mutex_lock(&mut_B);
mutex_look(&mut_A);
// critical section
mutex_unlock((&mut_A);
mutex_unlock(&mut_B);

is that a problem?

Notice:
The program is designed for a real-time system with a real-time kernel (RT-Linux). It is much more complicated and includes priorities for threads as well. However, for now, that is just additional information.


I do not agree to your statement 'Using one global mutex for everything goes against the model principle'.
You have one set of volatile data in your struct device named input and output. That should only accessed by one thread only. To avoid concurrent access you need one protector for it -- the one mutex.
Consider to use PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE attribute to allow recursive locks.
Consider also to use a MRSW lock (Multiple Readers / Single Writers) which allows read-only access from multiple threads without blocking.
